# Rename column names all by once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to add one word in the middle of column names. Like suffix, but not at the end:
Example:

value_1    value_2   value_3

Desired output: 
value_session_1    value_session_2   value_session_3

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_', '_session_')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` with `format`, there is possible add also string before or after:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: '{0[0]}_session_{0[1]}'.format(x.split('_')))
```

Or solution from [comment of John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843604/rename-column-names-all-by-once/44843690#comment76667456_44843604) with [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_', '_session_')
```

Samples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['value_1','value_2','value_3'])
print (df)  
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [value_1, value_2, value_3]
Index: []
```

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: '{0[0]}_session_{0[1]}'.format(x.split('_')))
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [value_session_1, value_session_2, value_session_3]
Index: []
```

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_', '_session_')
print (df)
Columns: [value_session_1, value_session_2, value_session_3]
Index: []
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['va_lue_1','va_lue_2','va_lue_3'])
print (df)  
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [va_lue_1, va_lue_2, va_lue_3]
Index: []

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: '{0[0]}_session_{0[1]}'.format(x.rsplit('_', 1)))
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [va_lue_session_1, va_lue_session_2, va_lue_session_3]
Index: []
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I have more than one '_' in column name? How to select the last one? Actually, I have where two '_' appeared, now more than two, so how select secont '_'

Comment: Longest answer maybe not the best answer.

Comment: @staticor - yes, sometimes I have to agree. But I think data sample is nice idea add to answer if OP not define it. Also sometimes answers are longer because edits

Answer (score 2):

[replacing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) is easy enough and should work:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_','_session')
```

Hope that helped. Happy Coding.

EDIT:
just like @jezrael mentionned